# select all checkbox_tag in rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am working on an app that have this code on a view file

```
<%= form_for @car, :html => { :method => :put }, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
   <h3 id="photos_count"><%= pluralize(@car.uploads.size, "Photo")%></h3>
   <div style="margin:10px 0 50px 0;float:left;width:700px;">
      <%= f.submit "Delete selected photos" %>
   </div>
   <div style="width:500px !important;">
     <%= f.fields_for :uploads do |photo_fields| %>
       <%unless photo_fields.object.new_record? %>
         <div style="width:150px;float:left;">
           <%= image_tag(photo_fields.object.photo.url(:thumb)) %>
           <p><%= photo_fields.check_box :_destroy %>  Delete item</p>
          </div>
       <% end %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

that generates a form with photos for cars that I can select one by one and then press Delete selected photo to delete them.

I need a select all check box or link at least.
I've google it and found solutions on how to do it, the reason why I can't test it is cause I am way too far from the working machine and I got the mail from the client to solve this asap.
I could not get how this things work.
I am online with the staff members from the server where the app is running and I just need the solution to give them.

the form generated by this code:
http://pastie.org/3013008

P.S. again, I would try to do this on my own but I am not on my working machine and I am on Windows platform on this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To select a checkbox via jquery, you change the checked property

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").prop("checked", true);
```

That will check all the input of type checkbox.
Depending on your situation, you might wanna change the selector

Now all u have to do is to bind this code to a link or a checkbox.

Comment: sure, I'll give you an answer when I'll test it out on my machine. cause I really have no idea what should I do with this one, I've found this examples on google too. thanks for you time